# include a gradle 'war' project in another project

Tags: java, gradle

I'm new to Gradle and trying to work out how to get my dependencies working correctly.

I have a project which builds a war using the 'war' plugin. I'd then like to use that project, and some other similar projects, to deploy those wars.

However, I can't work out how to make the project which is responsible for assembling these other projects dependent on the war projects.

The project 'war1' has a single 'war' method, I’ve tried the following
dependencies, none of which work:

```
dependencies {
    war project(path: ':war1')
    /* or */ compile project(path: ':war1')
    /* or */ assemble project(path: ':war1')
}
```

Could not find method xxx() for arguments [DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':war1', configuration='default'}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify dependencies on .war artifacts in Gradle like this example...

```
dependencies {
    runtime "org.jasig.cas:cas-server-webapp:3.5.2@war"
}
```

NOTE:  this example is for an external dependency, not a dependency on another sub-project within the same multi-project setup.  Looking at the [api docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html#project(java.util.Map)), it appears that you would do that like this...

```
dependencies {
    runtime project(path: ':war1', configuration: 'war')
}
```

Also --  perhaps you could benefit from the [Gradle WAR overlay plugin](https://github.com/scalding/gradle-waroverlay-plugin).  This plugin allows you to "enhance" a war dependency by adding or tweaking a few files within it, and thereby provide some configuration choices that your project knows about, but the original war didn't.

Comment: This seems to return the error: Could not find method runtime() for arguments [DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':war1'', configuration='war'}]

Comment: Ah, sorry -- you need to specify a Configuration (e.g. `compile`, `test`, etc.) that exists in your project and makes sense for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was able to import a war-file with Gradle 7.3; but I had to use "archives" for configuration.